# Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.CSharp.dll

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

Does anybody knows which Nuget package contains Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.CSharp.dll?

This DLL should be part of the Roslyn project e.g.:

http://sourceroslyn.io/#Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.CSharp/CodeModel/Interop/ICSAutoImplementedPropertyExtender.cs

but it looks like it is not installed either in Microsoft.Net.Compilers 2.3.0 or in Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.

Thanks in advance.

Marw

Comment: Why do you need that DLL?

Answer (score 1):

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.package.languageservice.aspx) says it is located in the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Package.LanguageService.14.0 assembly.

[This link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices/) should also be helpful:

> .NET Compiler Platform ("Roslyn") support for Visual Studio.
>
> Supported Platforms:
>
> .NET Framework 4.6
>   To install Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices, run the following command in the Package Manager Console:
>
> `Install-Package
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices -Version 2.2.0`

Answer (score -1):

I believe it is contained within a Nuget package called Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.

Instructions on how to install the package, as quoted from https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn

> To install the latest release without Visual Studio, run one of the
> following nuget command lines:
>
> nuget install Microsoft.Net.Compilers # Install C# and VB compilers
>
> nuget install Microsoft.CodeAnalysis    # Install Language APIs and
> Services

Comment: No, it's not. [That package](http://dotnetapis.com/pkg/Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices/2.2.0) contains only one DLL: Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.dll.